# has_changes_to_save? is not working for accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`has_changes_to_save?` return false when I change value of nested_attributes.

`has_changes_to_save?` should not be used for `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?
Is there another solution to check changes before save ?

Method

```
def update_meeting
  @meeting.attributes = meeting_params
          
  redirect_to edit_meeting_path and return unless @meeting.has_changes_to_save?

  @meeting.save

end
```

Console

```
>> meeting_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"start_date"=>"2021/02/26", "start_time"=>"09:15", "end_time"=>"09:45", "kind"=>"web", "location"=>"xxx", "address"=>"", "phone_number"=>"xxx", "pin_code"=>"", "web_url"=>"https://www.google.com/", "web_meeting_id"=>"", "web_meeting_passcode"=>"", "ir_meeting_ir_speakers_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters {"ir_speaker_id"=>"222", "_destroy"=>"1"} permitted: true>, "1"=><ActionController::Parameters {"ir_speaker_id"=>"626", "_destroy"=>"0"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>

>> @meeting
=> #<IrMeeting id: 111, user_id: 111, stock_id: 111, kind: "web", location: "xxx", address: "", speaker: "", start_at: "2021-02-26 00:15:00", end_at: "2021-02-26 00:45:00", remarks: nil, phone_number: "xxx", pin_code: "", web_url: "https://www.google.com/", web_meeting_id: "", web_meeting_passcode: "", required_document_count: nil, created_at: "2021-02-12 08:58:34", updated_at: "2021-02-12 10:34:20">
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ActiveRecord::Dirty (which is where your `has_changes_to_save?` comes from) doesn't work well with nested attributes. You could save the meeting and verify that the `updated_at` timestamps haven't changed.

```
def update_meeting
  @meeting.attributes = meeting_params
  last_updated = [@meeting.updated_at, @meeting.nested_models.order('updated_at DESC').first].max

  @meeting.save
  if last_updated == [@meeting.updated_at, @meeting.nested_models.order('updated_at DESC').first].max
    # neither message or nested models were changed
    redirect_to edit_meeting_path(meeting)
  end
end
```

Comment: Could also validate the association. Look for the `:validate` section. Also can look at validates_associated. https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many and https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated